# What can be inferred about the norm of a function from the integral of its product with another function that does not change sign

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, mean-value-theorem

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that, for a given $y$, $g(x,y)$ does not change sign in the interval $[a,b]$ of $x$ and its derivatives are bounded.

Also, let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable function such that, for a given $y$, it attains a single maximum in the interior of the $x$-axis interval $[a,b]$, and its derivatives are bounded.

For $y = y_0$, definite integral of the product of these two functions over $[a,b]$ is zero, i.e.,
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y_0) g(x,y_0) dx = 0.
$$

Furthermore, in the neighborhood of $y=y_0$, this integral takes the same sign as the difference $y-y_0$.
That is, for example, when $y = y_+ > y_0$, the integral is positive, i.e.,
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x,y_+) g(x,y_+) dx > 0.
$$

Can I infer anything about any norm of the function $f(x,y)$ locally in some neighborhood of $y=y_0$ from what is provided above?

P.S. This is my research and not a homework. The problem I'm asking here is a distilled down version of a bigger problem I'm stuck at. I've been pondering about this problem (tried using MVT for definite integrals and Holder's inequality to name a few things I've done) but couldn't find anything really useful.

Comment: Your question is, in my opinion, way too broad. If $g_y:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ were bounded, you could manipulate each $f_y,$ maybe a function such as $f(x,y)=C_1^{(y)}|x|\chi_{\left[a,\frac{a+b}2\right]}(x)+C_2^{(y)}|x|\chi_{\left\langle\frac{a+b}2,b\right]}(x)$ might work if you optimize constants $C_1^{(y)},C_2^{(y)}\in\Bbb R,$ one positive and one negative, which would depend on $y$ to meet your criteria. But this doesn't answer the question of necessary conditions on $f.$

Comment: I understand. 
I am actually not looking for global necessary conditions. Properties of f in some local neighborhood of $y$ would be sufficient.